# how to search multi level array in php

Tags: php, json

I am new to php and really could do with a little help please.
I have my base contected to my site and wish to search a table based on a reference number and return the results.
I'm stuck searching a multi level array - I have tried several things I have found on the web but no luck. Any advise please.

Comment: Is your search supposed to find a particular `record`? What is the criteria?

Comment: hi - I want the table to hold the user details such as phone etc and the user on my website will have the same ref code so I want to search table based on 'ref' and get the 'phone' for that user. hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search the array with `array_filter` somthing like this:

```
$reference_number = "your reference number to compare against";

// just basing this off the array you show in your question
$input_array = $input[0]["records"];

// filter input
$found_records = array_filter($input_array, function($record){
    return $record["id"] === $reference_number;
});

// check if any are found then do something with it
if ($found_records) {
    $phone = $found_records[0]["fields"]["phone"];
}
```

Comment: AAMazing thank you - I needed to edit this line  $phone = $found_records[0]["fields"]["phone"];   But you have saved me loads of time I appreciated it!!

Comment: Nice, happy to help.  Updated my answer to include `fields` just to be correct.